# Installing Janusgraph on google cloud

Tags: gcloud, janusgraph

I am trying to install JanusGraph on google cloud using the tutorial available at the https://cloud.google.com/architecture/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable

But i am getting an error  `unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1"`, and getting the chart deprecated error . Let me know if any one is able to install the same,

With  as per the documentation

```sh
gcloud container clusters create janusgraph-tutorial \
--cluster-version=1.15 \
--machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
--scopes=\
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.admin",\
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data"
```

The error was  `ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=400, message=No valid versions with the prefix "1.15" found`.

So i tried:

```sh
gcloud container ...
--cluster-version=1.20 \ ..
```

and i was able to create the container

later janus graph installation

```sh
helm upgrade --install --wait --timeout 600s janusgraph stable/janusgraph -f values.yaml

Release "janusgraph" does not exist. Installing it now.
WARNING: This chart is deprecated
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta1", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta1"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes versions resources like `Deployment`. Until recently (<=1.16), `Deployment` was available under the `apps/v1beta1` API (version). Since Kubernetes 1.16 this is deprecated and removed. You must now use `apps/v1`.

See:

- [Deprecated APIs Removed in 1.16](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/)
- [Kubernetes API Reference 1.21](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#deployment-v1-apps)

If you're able to revise these references in the tutorial, then you should do so. You may encounter other APIs that are deprecated and|or removed but only the latter should cause similar problems.

It may be preferable to "Send feedback" (bottom of tutorial) to Google asking that someone there upgrade the tutorial or provide caveats.

Curiously, I noticed that the tutorial includes creating a Kubernetes v1.15 cluster:

```sh
gcloud container clusters create janusgraph-tutorial \
--cluster-version=1.15 \
...
```

Per the above, that version should still support `apps/v1beta1/Deployment` did that not work?

Your question would benefit from additional context|detail. You write "I am getting an error" but you do not include the specific step that cause this issue. I assume it was when you attempted to deploy JanusGraph to the cluster using Helm?

```sh
helm upgrade --install ... 600s janusgraph stable/janusgraph -f values.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks DazWilkin for your reponse.. i have updated the question with more details

Comment: Your updated question confirms my answer. GKE won't permit you to install the outdated version of Kubernetes used by the tutorial (`1.15`) and the tutorial was written using a Kubernetes resources (`app/v1beta1/Deployment`) that is no longer available in current versions of Kubernetes. The solution is to get the tutorial updated to use e.g. `apps/v1/Deployment` (and possibly other now no longer available resources) or find another tutorial.